# Como insertar estiquetas html en medio de un json

Tags: html, json, nodejs, angular, mongodb

espero que anden bien , tengo una duda toy haciendo un proyecto de noticias , utilizando en **MEAN** stack

les dejo uno de mis modelos para poner en contexto

> modelo:

```
'use strict'
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = Schema({
    epigrafe:String,
    title: String,
    subtitulo:String,
    year: String,
    description:String,
    imageM: String,
    imageP: String,
    imageS: String,
    imageT: String,
    imageC: String,
    imageQ: String,
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Medicina', ProjectSchema);
```

en descripcion van los párrafos de las noticias, hasta ahí todo bien. mi problema me surge al querer poner una imagen entre párrafos.

es decir, si mi noticia tiene 5  parrafos solo puedo poner una imagen arriba de dichos parrafos o debajo de los mismos, pero si quisiera poner una imagen entre el parrafo 4 - 5 (por dar un ejemplo) ¿como podria hacer ?

edit: logro poner una etiqueta dentro de el json , pero me lo toma en formato de texto, no logro que se lea una etiqueta.

> mi html

```
<div class="contenedor-noticiaActual">
<div class="titulo-compartir" *ngIf="economia">
    <h2>{{economia.epigrafe}}</h2>
    <!-- agregar para compartir -->
    <hr>
    <div class="fecha-titulo">
      <h5>{{economia.year}}</h5>
      <h1>{{economia.title}}</h1>
      <br>
      <h4>{{economia.subtitulo}}</h4>
    </div>

</div>
      <div class="seccion-noticiaAct">

        <hr>
        <img src="{{ url+'get-image/'+economia.imageP }}">
        <hr>
          <div class="infoProyecto">
                <p class="parrafos">{{economia.description}}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

> lo que utilizo para buscar el texto y reemplazarlo

```
  // metodo para buscar la noticia
  getEconomia(id){

    this._noticiasService.getEconomia(id).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.economia = response.economia;



            // reemplazar el texto "acaImagenUno"
            if (this.economia.description.indexOf("acaImagenUno")) {
                this._noticiasService.updateEconomia(this.economia).subscribe(
                response => {
                    if(response.economia){
                      let imagenUn = this.economia.imageM;

                      this.imgs=document.createElement("img");  
                      this.imgs.setAttribute("class", "claseDiv");
                      console.log(this.economia.imageP);

                      this.imgs.setAttribute("src", this.url+'get-image/'+ imagenUn  );
                      console.log("laconcha de tu madre"+this.imgs.appendChild);
                      let busqueda =  this.economia.description.indexOf("acaImagenUno");



                      let reemplazo =this.economia.description.replace("acaImagenUno", `${(this.imgs).outerHTML} `  );
                      this.economia.description = reemplazo;



                      this.save_economia = response.economia;
                      this.status = 'success';



                  }else{
                    this.status = 'failed';
                  }
                  },
                  error => {
                    console.log(<any>error);
                  }
                );
              }
            },

            error =>{
                console.log(<any>error);
            }

    )
  }
```

> como se ve mi html sin modificarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> como se ve mi html luego de modificarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Porqué quieres guardar la estructura de la vista en un campo del documento de la base de datos? En todo caso ¿cómo pretendes guardar dicha estructura? Dices que no pones más código por ser *irrelevante*, pero como yo lo veo, es la parte más relevante.

Comment: lo que puedes guardar es la url de las imágenes, es mas factible

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que menciona @Enzo, puedes guardar la imágenes en un servicio de almacenamiento (ya sea tu propio servidor web/VPS, Firebase, Amazon S3, etc) y almacenar las referencias o, si no dispones de ello, almacenando las imagenes como un Data URI Base64.

Comment: @MauricioContreras hola , solo mostre el modelo de mi backend, tengo un modelo que se muestra en el  front-end y paso la informacion  por medio de servicios.

mostre esa parte para que tengan en cuenta las variables que utilizo.

Comment: @Enzo , eso hice con las imagenes ,pero por separado, desde la imageM hasta la imageQ, existe algun caracter especial para referenciar imagenes de una url ? es que soy bastante novato y no encuentro nada al respecto. gracias por responder

Comment: las imagenes las introducis vos manualmente o eso lo hace el usuario final ?

Comment: @Enzo tengo una seccion de administrador donde yo pongo el contenido y lo guardo, voy a ver si puedo editar este articulo, por que pude avanzar y estoy atascado nuevamente